# How to use config file provider plugin with groovy

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins file which is loading a groovy script and want to use the config-file-provider plugin in groovy.  I read on the documentation that support was added but don't really know how to add it using groovy to use a particular settings.xml file when running a mvn clean install -s settings.xml.  Looks like this plugin is supported on this list -> https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md

Comment: How to declare the config file provider only once in the main node block in scripted JenkinsFile and refer to it from all different stages.

Answer (score 5):

Wondering if you found the answer, the maven example with groovy (groovy used for a pipeline) is actually documented in the plugin page, here:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin#ConfigFileProviderPlugin-UsingtheconfigurationfilesinJenkinsPipelines

```
node {

    git url: 'https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git'

    // install Maven and add it to the path
    env.PATH = "${tool 'M3'}/bin:${env.PATH}"

    configFileProvider(
        [configFile(fileId: 'maven-settings', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
        sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS clean package'
    }

}
```

I just tried to put a similar block in my pipeline, inside a stage step, it worked. Note, in the above example, `MAVEN_SETTINGS` is the path to a temporary XML file. `maven-settings` is the ID of the file created via config file provider plugin.

Comment: Using the `configFileProvider` wrapper, then removing it from the pipeline may keep the job runs successful due to a "cached" configuration file remaining in the workspace.  Lesson learned: the `configFileProvider` pipeline wrapper is not optional to adding a `settings.xml` file in the folder configuration, even when specifying the target file name.

Comment: Is there a way to change something in that configurations file? For example I have ordinary file (not xml) where I have `Number=1` and I want it to change to `Number=2`. How can I do that?

Comment: How is MAVEN_SETTINGS defined in the config file? MAVEN_SETTINGS=/some/path/temp.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

When I use JenkinsPipeline I have a step for adding the configuration files before building step. It works for any type of build, not only maven. 
However I had difficulties when writing a function in vars to coupe with a dynamic list of configuration files.

```
 stage('Add Config files') {
        steps {
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'JenkinsIDForFile1', targetLocation: 'DestinationFileForFile1')]) {
            // some block
            }
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'JenkinsIDForFile1', targetLocation: 'DestinationFileForFile2')]) {
            // some block
            }
        }
 }
```

If you could use '-' in the ID use double qutes: "File-ID-with-dash"